# Select specific image name in subfolder search

Tags: php, image, if-statement, directory

I'm using the following code to search for all the images in all the subfolders of a directory:

```
        function get_images10($root) {

            $r = array();
            foreach(glob("$root/*") as $n) {
                if (is_dir($n)) {
                    $r = array_merge($r, get_images10($n));
                } else {
                   $r[] = $n;
                }
            }

            return $r;
        }
```

It works fine, but now I would like to limit the search only to the images that contain in their filename the suffix "thumb-".
In another script I have used the following:

```
if ((strpos($filename,'thumb-') !== false)) {
  //some code
}
```

But I have no idea where to put such statement (if) in the above mentioned code.
Any idea on how I could do that?

Comment: is `thumb-` a prefix or a suffix? in any case, rather than using `strpos()`, you should be able to modify your `glob()` instead

Comment: You don't have a lot of code there. Why not use trial & error?

Comment: By suffix, do you mean prefix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming it's a prefix, since it ends with `-`. Anyway, you'd do it in the `else` as an `elseif`:

```
function get_images10($root) {
    $r = array();

    foreach(glob("$root/*") as $n) {
        if (is_dir($n)) {
            $r = array_merge($r, get_images10($n));
        } elseif (strpos($n, 'thumb-') !== false) {
            $r[] = $n;
        }
    }

    return $r;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If 'thumb-' is a prefix in the filename, you can just change line 3 to:

```
foreach(glob("$root/thumb-*") as $n) {
```

Comment: That won't get any subdirectory, though.

Comment: that's right, if you need that I think your way is the best way